# How can i overload assignment operator for double pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, copy, deep-copy

```
MyType **arr;
```

how can i overload operator= for deep copy i mean

```
MyType **arr1 = ...;
MyType **arr2 = ...;
arr1 = arr2; // <-deep copy
```

can somebody guide me how to do such a thing?
MyType contains only primitive types. So i think the body of class is not necessary, just want a pattern.

Comment: You cannot overload operators for built-in types (thank heaven).

Comment: `arr1 = arr2; // <-deep copy` -- That is the deepest copy you can have.  You want to do something more than that, create a class.  Also, what if the programmer actually wants to assign the pointer to another pointer?  How will your code work?

Comment: you should never have owning raw pointers in C++, let alone double pointers. Use C++ abstractions like containers and smart pointers and you don't need to worry about this stuff at all.